# Send `null` to browser instead of `{}`

Tags: go

I want to able to send `null` to the browser as JSON, if I do this:

```
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(nil)
```

then `null` will be received by the browser. However in this context:

```
var nearby map[string]Nearby

// ...

func GetOne(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    item := nearby[params["id"]] // item could be nil?
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(item)
}
```

if nothing exists in the map, then `{}` will be received by the browser instead of `null`...is there some way I can send `null` if the key is not in the map?

Comment: Show the declaration and type of `nearby`.

Comment: sure thing, I updated the OP

Comment: Now show the definition of Nearby

Comment: `Nearby` is a struct with a couple fields, nothing crazy

Comment: This doesn't have to do with the struct failing to have capital first letters, different kinda issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the comments on the quesiton, the map value is a struct. A struct cannot have the value `nil`.

If the intent is to write `null` when there's no value in the map, then explicitly write the `null` in that case:

```
item, ok := nearby[params["id"]]
if ok {
   json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(item)
} else {
   io.WriteString(w, "null")
   // Can also use json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(nil), but that involves more machinery.
}
```

Comment: thanks, what does the `ok` var represent here? I am a golang newb

Comment: FYI, `json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(nil)` will send `null` tho

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman The value of ok is true if the key is present in the map, and false otherwise.

Comment: got it, if the key is not present in the map, why is `item` not `nil` is my question!

Comment: `item` is set to the zero value of the struct.  See [the specification for the details](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions). A struct cannot have the value `nil`.

Comment: hmmm looking up a key that's not in the map should point to nothing/nil, not to a zero value...I guess that's just how golang works. trying to avoid the billion dollar mistake, seems kinda dumb tho.

Comment: The map index expression evaluates to a struct value, not a pointer to a struct value.

Comment: you can think of it as all map implementations return the "zero" value when they can't retrieve something.  In languages that are restricted to only allowing reference types (ie: Java), it returns the zero value of a reference (which is null).   If you wanted similar behaivor in go, you would store pointers (*Nearby) which will give you nil if the item was missing.   The fact that go lets you treat structs as values and store those values in a map isn't so much dumb as it is a feature missing from some other languages